# Getting common characters of two strings results in "ValueError: not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I want to print uncommon characters in 2 strings but I am unable to do so because when I run the code I get the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

I have created 2 strings and I am trying to iterate through each character in the string by storing them in those 2 variables `a` and `b` and then replacing them with the next character as the loop continues. Finally, I have added the if-condition that at any point in the iteration if the values in `a` and `b` match then first print the common characters.

Both the print commands must display `"ho"` as the output, however, I am getting the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` instead.

```
string_s1 = "Hello"
string_s2 = "Python"

for a, b in string_s1 and string_s2:

   if a == b:
      print(a)
      print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are some problems to solve:

1. Why the `not enough values to unpack` exception is raised? This is because `a and b` returns `b` if `a` is `True`, else returns `a`. Therefore, while `a` and `b` are both nonempty, `a and b` always returns string `b`, i.e. `string_s2` is returned in your code. That is to say, in your `for` loop, the string `string_s2` is evaluated to the tuple `a,b`, that's why you got the exception -- Python doesn't know how to unpack a string to two vars.
2. What should you do if not `a and b`? Well, in such case, `zip(string_s1,,string_s2)` SEEMS to be a solution, but not what you want. Your expect output is `ho`, which means nested `for` loop is actual solution.
3. Be careful about the case of letters. If the letter `h` is in your output, then the letter `H` in `Hello` must be converted to lower case before comparing.

So, the code you want may be:

```
string_s1 = "Hello"
string_s2 = "Python"

for a in string_s1:
    for b in string_s2:
        a,b = map(str.lower,(a,b))
        if a == b:
            print(a,end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use zip. This will handle the case where the strings are of different lengths

```
string_s1 = "Hello"
string_s2 = "Python"

for a, b in zip(string_s1, string_s2):

   if a == b:
      print(a)
      print(b)
```